# Display the results of a query if the query is executed

Tags: php, mysqli

What I am trying to do is get the values of the $r variable (returns some vehicle id values) to display on the page. However, it returns the following error.

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be
> converted to string in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\SAMADHI\system\module\reservation\controller\reservationcontroller.php
> on line 166

The problem is on the `echo $r` statement. I tried echo '$r' but then it shows nothing even though it displays the the message 'vehicle available'.

```
if ($nor > 0) {
    $r = $objs->searchVehicle($vhandover, $vreturn, $seatcap);
    if ($r) {
        $msg = "Vehicle available";               
        $status = 1;
        echo $r;       
    } else {
        $msg = "Something is not right!";
        $status = 0;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I correct it?

Comment: $r is not a string

Comment: `$r` is not `String` type. It returns an associative array. Try `$r['columnName']`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it and it said $r cannot be displayed as an array. And i used a fetch_assoc(). $a=$r->fetch_assoc(). still it just displays the message and not the vehicle ids....

Comment: please see my answer bellow, you need to put the `echo` inside a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume, your vehicle table have following column - `id, name, type`. When your query executes, `$r` holds an associative array with search result-

```
$r = [ ['id'=>1, 'name'=>"toyota", 'type'=> "regular"], ....]
```

This is not any `String`. So if you want to `echo` any of the column value you need to mention it like -

```
echo $r['name'];
```

But if your query returns multiple results then, you need to put the `echo` inside a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($r as $row) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

**UPDATE**
If the above code doesn't work for you then try the following-

```
while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

**UPDATE: 2**
You can use `fetch_array($r)` -

```
while ($row = fetch_array($r)) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Hope that clears your concept!

Comment: Hi again. Yes, my query returns multiple results. I tried this code as well. Still it didn't display anything... I even double checked the query. It works fine.

Comment: It still did not work. i was wondering..., I don't have to get the id by some post or get method since it will be fetched by the query, do I?

Comment: no, you don't. can you please post the code portion of `searchVehicalId()`

Comment: function searchVehicle($vhandover,$vreturn,$seatcap){
        $con = $GLOBALS['con'];
        $sql = "SELECT v.v_id FROM vehicle v WHERE v.v_id NOT IN (SELECT r.v_id FROM reservation r, vehicle v 
            WHERE (('$vhandover' between r.vhandover AND r.vreturn) OR ('$vreturn' between r.vhandover AND r.vreturn)) 
                AND r.v_id=v.v_id AND v.vseatcap='$seatcap') AND v.vseatcap='$seatcap'";
        $result = $con->query($sql);        
        return $result;
    }

Comment: then use `fetch_array($r)` inside `while` condition.

Comment: I tried all the given methods. but none of them are working.... but thank you so much for your help.